# JavaScript style body outside iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, google-dfp, skin

How can the outermost body tag be styled using JavaScript from inside the innermost body tag of an iFrame?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ad_tag" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;">
      <div id="ad_container" style="border: 0pt none;">
        <iframe id="ad_iframe" title="title" name="name" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: bottom;" srcdoc="" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0">
          <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
              <script>
              parent.document.body.style.background = "url('https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/photos/000/676/67655.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed #ffffff";
              </script>
            </body>
          </html>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- In this specific case:

  - No direct editing of attributes or styling allowed, existing are preset.
  - Only child elements of the innermost body can be edited.
  - The goal is to deliver a background image using Google DFP.

Comment: Does the iframe have permission to access the parent document?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be with a post message from the frame, that the parent (the site) will execute through listener.
So your iframe should contain some code like:

```
<script>
     window.parent.postMessage({
        'func': 'changeBackground',
        'message': ''
    }, "*");
</script>
```

And your parent (the site) should contain a listener like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);       
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", onMessage, false);
}



function onMessage(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    if (typeof(window[data.func]) == "function") {
        window[data.func].call(null, data.message);
    }
}

function changeBackground(message) {

    $('div#backgroundwrapper').css({
        'background-image': 'url("https:/example.com/example.jpg")',
    $('div#backgroundwrapper').click();
        var win = window.open( '%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%', '_blank');
    win.focus();
    });
}
</script>
```

In my example, it will put the image file as a background on a div with ID backgroundwrapper. My example uses jQuery to change the CSS and adding a clicktag, but it could be made without it as well.